# How to write MongoDB request?

Tags: mongodb

Here is an example of a type document:

```
{
    id: 't-123'
    attributes: [
       {
          id: 'a-1',
          type: 'INPUT'
       },
       {
          id: 'a-2',
          type: 'SELECT',
          option: [
             {key: 'DE', label: 'Germany'},
             {key: 'US', label: 'United States'}
          ]
       }
    ]
}
```

Additionally, I have a form collection that references the type collection and stores all filled fields from a user.

Here is an example of a form document:

```
{
    id: 'f-1',
    type: 't-123',
    values: [
      {attribute: 'a-1', value: 'my random string'},
      {attribute: 'a-2', value: 'DE'} 
    ]
}
```

Now, I am trying to query the form collection and automatically add the choosen key/label object from the type collection for fields with type: SELECT.

Here is my desired result:

```
{
    id: 'f-1',
    type: 't-123',
    values: [
      {attribute: 'a-1', value: 'my random string'},
      {attribute: 'a-2', value: {key:'DE', label:'Germany'}} 
    ]
}
```

Comment: whats the "chosen" key/label? why wasent {key: US, label: "United States"} chosen for example?

Comment: @tomslabbaert, "chosen" means that select in UI.
option: [
             {key: 'DE', label: 'Germany'},
             {key: 'US', label: 'United States'}
             {key: 'IL', label: 'Israel'}
              ......
              additional
          ]